# MYSQL increment 'SHOWN' row for WHERE matching rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a solution for table 'A" which structure is:

```
ID      NAME    SHOWN
1       Eddie    0
2       Marie    1
3       Shawn    15
4       Frank    12
5       Danny    7
```

I'd like to commit a SELECT on this table so that for each resulted row, the '`SHOWN`' would increase, so for example:

```
SELECT * from 'A' WHERE `ID`>3;
```

would cause table 'A' the following change:

```
ID      NAME    SHOWN
1       Eddie    0
2       Marie    1
3       Shawn    15
4       Frank    13
5       Danny    8
```

Only Frank and Danny's ID is bigger than 3, so the resulting SELECT would yield Frank and Danny and so, their respective '`SHOWN`' column is increased by 1

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may update your table with the expected increment then.

```
UPDATE A
SET SHOWN = SHOWN + 1
WHERE ID > 3
```

Check the this reference out :)

### [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/817fbe/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
update A set shown=shown+1 where ID >3)
```

here is the [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c38b)

Comment: There's no need for the `IN()` clause. Just `WHERE ID > 3` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with a `CASE` expression:

```
select  ID
      , NAME
      , CASE WHEN SHOWN > 3 THEN SHOWN + 1 ELSE SHOWN END as SHOWN
FROM A
```